# Masonry, WP_Query & paged - first page repeating, second page not loading

Tags: wp-query, paged, masonry

I'm tearing my hair out over this. I've been tasked with some legacy work on a quite an old site. They have a template for a custom post type called resources.

This template has search/filtering functionality which is working as intended, however the masonry/load more functionality is broken. The first set of resources loaded are featured resources.

When clicking 'load more' the template executes query, ignoring any featured posts and loading the next batch. It does this fine on first batch but then on the second it just adds in the first batch to the grid. It will do this over and over never showing more than the top featured posts and repeating the first posts.

Here's the template (I realise it's a lot but I didn't want to miss anything out other than the top part of the template with template names)  -

```
get_header();

//==============================================================================
//===GET FILTER VARIABLES ======================================================
//==============================================================================

$filter_option_array = isset($_POST['option'])? trim($_POST['option']) : false;
$filter_group_array = isset($_POST['group'])? trim(strtolower($_POST['group'])) : false;
$received_vars=false;

//===============================================================================
// VERIFY THE DATA RECEIVED  :
//===============================================================================
if( $filter_option_array && $filter_group_array ){ $received_vars=true;
}

    //==============================================================================
    //SET PAGE VARIABLES
    //==============================================================================
    $page_id = get_the_ID();

    $limit_per_page = 15;
    $featured_count = 0;
    $result= array();
    $searchx ='';

    $meta_key = $meta_value = $search_term = $no_results = '';
    $remove = array('&', '#038;',' ');

    //==============================================================================
    //FILTER OPTIONS INTO ARRAYS TO PRE SELECT DROP DOWNS
    //==============================================================================
    if($received_vars===true){

        $filter_option  = explode("|",$filter_option_array);
        $filter_group   = explode("|",$filter_group_array);
        $advice='';


        for($h=0; $h<count($filter_option); $h++){

            $result[$h] = GetMetaKeysValues($filter_group[$h],$filter_option[$h]);
            //result[0][0]= meta_value
            //result[0][1]= meta_key
            //result[0][2]= no_results
            //result[0][3]= search_term
            //result[0][4]= filter_group
        }

        //Capture the option value to preselect the dropdowns ===================
        $service_match = $juris_match = $sector_match ='';
        foreach($filter_group as $key => $value){

            switch($value){
                case 3: $juris_match  = $filter_option[$key]; break;
                case 2: $sector_match = $filter_option[$key]; break;
                case 1: $service_match= $filter_option[$key]; break;
            }
            //echo $key.'--'.$value.'--'.$filter_option[$key].'<br/>';
        }

        //build the no-found results string
        foreach($result as $value){
            $advice.= $value[2].' + ';
            if($value[3]!=''){$searchx = $value[3]; }
        }
        $advice = substr($advice, 0, -3);

    }



    //==============================================================================
    //NO RESULT FOUND MESSAGE ======================================================
    //==============================================================================
    $empty = 'No resources found '; if($advice != ''){$empty.= 'under "<strong>'.$advice.'"</strong>';};



    //==============================================================================
    //GET PAGINATION VARIABLE  =======================================
    //==============================================================================
    $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;


    //==============================================================================
    //GET FEATURED RESOURCES ====================================
    //==============================================================================
    //'meta_key' => '_is_ns_featured_post', 'meta_value' => 'yes'

    $featured_args = array(

        'order'             => 'ASC',
        'meta_key'          => '_is_ns_featured_post',
        'meta_value'        => 'yes',
        'post_type'         => 'resource',
        'post_status'       => 'publish',
        'suppress_filters'  => false,
    );

    $featured_posts = new WP_Query( $featured_args );
    $have_featured = ($featured_posts->found_posts > 0)? true : false;



    //==============================================================================
    //DISPLAY FEATURED POST FIRST:  ONLY FOR FIRST PAGE ===============
    //==============================================================================
    if(($have_featured===true) && ($paged == 1) ):



        //==============================================================================
        //SHOW FEATURED ONLY IF NO SEARCH IS SUMMON
        //===========================================================

        if($received_vars===true){ //DO FILTER

            //======================================================
            //DO SEARCH COMBINATIONS ===============================
            //======================================================

            switch(count($result)) {

                case 1:

                    //====================================================================
                    //PLACE FEATURED IF ANY ON TOP =======================================
                    //====================================================================
                    $on_top = FeaturedOnTop($featured_posts, $have_featured, $result);
                    //$on_top[0] =  $found;
                    //$on_top[1] =  $match_ids;

                    if($on_top[0]===true){

                        //GET FEATURED BY MATCHED ID FOUND
                        $f_args = array(

                            'orderby'           => 'menu_order',
                            'order'             => 'ASC',
                            'post__in'          => $on_top[1],
                            'post_type'         => 'resource',
                            'post_status'       => 'publish',
                            'suppress_filters'  => false,
                        );

                        $top_resources = new WP_Query( $f_args );

                        $cs_args = array(
                            'posts_per_page' => -1,
                            'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                            'order'  => 'ASC',
                            'offset' => 0,
                            'meta_query' => array(
                                array(
                                    'key' => $result[0][1],
                                    'value' => $result[0][0],
                                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                                )
                            ),
                            'post_type' => 'resource',
                            'post__not_in' => $on_top[1],
                            'post_status' => 'publish',

                        );

                        $bottom_resources = new WP_Query($cs_args);

                        //MERGE BOTH QUERIES
                        $resources = new WP_Query();
                        $resources->posts = array_merge( $top_resources->posts, $bottom_resources->posts );

                        //merge counters
                        $resources->post_count = $top_resources->post_count + $bottom_resources->post_count;
                        $resources->found_posts = $top_resources->found_posts + $bottom_resources->found_posts;

                    //====================================================================
                    }else{ //NORMAL SEARCH 1
                    //====================================================================
                        $cs_args = array(
                            'posts_per_page' => -1,
                            'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                            'order'  => 'ASC',
                            'offset' => 0,
                            'meta_query' => array(
                                array(
                                    'key' => $result[0][1],
                                    'value' => $result[0][0],
                                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                                )
                            ),
                            'post_type' => 'resource',
                            'post_status' => 'publish',
                            //'paged' => $paged,
                        );

                        $resources = new WP_Query($cs_args);

                    }



                    //=============================================================
                    //IF NO RESULTS GET ALL RESOURCES TAG "ALL"
                    //=============================================================
                    if($resources->found_posts == 0){


                        $cs_args = array(
                            'posts_per_page' => -1,
                            'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                            'order'  => 'ASC',
                            'offset' => 0,
                            'meta_query' => array(
                                array(
                                    'key' => $result[0][4],
                                    'value' => true,
                                    'compare' => '='
                                )
                            ),
                            'post_type' => 'resource',
                            'post_status' => 'publish',

                        );

                        $resources = new WP_Query($cs_args);

                    }
                    break;



                case 2:

                    //====================================================================
                    //PLACE FEATURED IF ANY ON TOP =======================================
                    //====================================================================
                    $on_top = FeaturedOnTop($featured_posts, $have_featured,  $result);
                    //$on_top[0] =  $found;
                    //$on_top[1] =  $match_ids;

                    if($on_top[0]===true){

                        //GET FEATURED BY MATCHED ID FOUND
                        $f_args = array(

                            'orderby'           => 'menu_order',
                            'order'             => 'ASC',
                            'post__in'          => $on_top[1],
                            'post_type'         => 'resource',
                            'post_status'       => 'publish',
                            'suppress_filters'  => false,
                        );

                        $top_resources = new WP_Query( $f_args );

                        $cs_args = array(
                            'posts_per_page' => -1,
                            'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                            'order'  => 'ASC',
                            'offset' => 0,
                            'meta_query' => array(
                                'relation' => 'AND',
                                array(
                                    'key' => $result[0][1],
                                    'value' => $result[0][0],
                                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                                ),
                                array(
                                    'key' => $result[1][1],
                                    'value' => $result[1][0],
                                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                                )
                            ),
                            'post__not_in' => $on_top[1],
                            'post_type' => 'resource',
                            'post_status' => 'publish',

                        );


                        $bottom_resources = new WP_Query($cs_args);

                        //MERGE BOTH QUERIES
                        $resources = new WP_Query();
                        $resources->posts = array_merge( $top_resources->posts, $bottom_resources->posts );

                        //merge counters
                        $resources->post_count = $top_resources->post_count + $bottom_resources->post_count;
                        $resources->found_posts = $top_resources->found_posts + $bottom_resources->found_posts;

                    //====================================================================
                    }else { //NORMAL SEARCH 2
                    //====================================================================
                        $cs_args = array(
                            'posts_per_page' => -1,
                            'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                            'order' => 'ASC',
                            'offset' => 0,
                            'meta_query' => array(
                                'relation' => 'AND',
                                array(
                                    'key' => $result[0][1],
                                    'value' => $result[0][0],
                                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                                ),
                                array(
                                    'key' => $result[1][1],
                                    'value' => $result[1][0],
                                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                                )
                            ),
                            'post_type' => 'resource',
                            'post_status' => 'publish',
                            //'paged' => $paged,
                        );

                        $resources = new WP_Query($cs_args);
                    }

                    //=============================================================
                    //IF NO RESULTS GET ALL RESOURCES TAG "ALL"
                    //=============================================================
                    if($resources->found_posts == 0){


                        $cs_args = array(
                            'posts_per_page' => -1,
                            'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                            'order'  => 'ASC',
                            'offset' => 0,
                            'meta_query' => array(
                                'relation' => 'AND',
                                array(
                                    'key' => $result[0][4],
                                    'value' => true,
                                    'compare' => '='
                                ),
                                array(
                                    'key' => $result[1][4],
                                    'value' => true,
                                    'compare' => '='
                                )
                            ),
                            'post_type' => 'resource',
                            'post_status' => 'publish',

                        );

                        $resources = new WP_Query($cs_args);

                    }
                    break;



                case 3:

                    //====================================================================
                    //PLACE FEATURED IF ANY ON TOP =======================================
                    //====================================================================
                    $on_top = FeaturedOnTop($featured_posts, $have_featured, $result);
                    //$on_top[0] =  $found;
                    //$on_top[1] =  $match_ids;

                    if($on_top[0]===true){

                        //GET FEATURED BY MATCHED ID FOUND
                        $f_args = array(

                            'orderby'           => 'menu_order',
                            'order'             => 'ASC',
                            'post__in'          => $on_top[1],
                            'post_type'         => 'resource',
                            'post_status'       => 'publish',
                            'suppress_filters'  => false,
                        );

                        $top_resources = new WP_Query( $f_args );

                        $cs_args = array(
                            'posts_per_page' => -1,
                            'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                            'order'  => 'ASC',
                            'offset' => 0,
                            'meta_query' => array(
                                'relation' => 'AND',
                                array(
                                    'key' => $result[0][1],
                                    'value' => $result[0][0],
                                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                                ),
                                array(
                                    'key' => $result[1][1],
                                    'value' => $result[1][0],
                                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                                ),
                                array(
                                    'key' => $result[2][1],
                                    'value' => $result[2][0],
                                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                                )
                            ),
                            'post__not_in' => $on_top[1],
                            'post_type' => 'resource',
                            'post_status' => 'publish',

                        );


                        $bottom_resources = new WP_Query($cs_args);

                        //MERGE BOTH QUERIES
                        $resources = new WP_Query();
                        $resources->posts = array_merge( $top_resources->posts, $bottom_resources->posts );

                        //merge counters
                        $resources->post_count = $top_resources->post_count + $bottom_resources->post_count;
                        $resources->found_posts = $top_resources->found_posts + $bottom_resources->found_posts;

                    //====================================================================
                    }else { //NORMAL SEARCH 3
                    //====================================================================

                        $cs_args = array(
                            'posts_per_page' => -1,
                            'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                            'order' => 'ASC',
                            'offset' => 0,
                            'meta_query' => array(
                                'relation' => 'AND',
                                array(
                                    'key' => $result[0][1],
                                    'value' => $result[0][0],
                                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                                ),
                                array(
                                    'key' => $result[1][1],
                                    'value' => $result[1][0],
                                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                                ),
                                array(
                                    'key' => $result[2][1],
                                    'value' => $result[2][0],
                                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                                )
                            ),
                            'post_type' => 'resource',
                            'post_status' => 'publish',
                            //'paged' => $paged,
                        );

                        $resources = new WP_Query($cs_args);
                    }
                    //=============================================================
                    //IF NO RESULTS GET ALL RESOURCES TAG "ALL"
                    //=============================================================
                    if($resources->found_posts == 0){


                        $cs_args = array(
                            'posts_per_page' => -1,
                            'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                            'order'  => 'ASC',
                            'offset' => 0,
                            'meta_query' => array(
                                'relation' => 'AND',
                                array(
                                    'key' => $result[0][4],
                                    'value' => true,
                                    'compare' => '='
                                ),
                                array(
                                    'key' => $result[1][4],
                                    'value' => true,
                                    'compare' => '='
                                ),
                                array(
                                    'key' => $result[2][4],
                                    'value' => true,
                                    'compare' => '='
                                )

                            ),
                            'post_type' => 'resource',
                            'post_status' => 'publish',

                        );

                        $resources = new WP_Query($cs_args);

                    }
                    break;
            }


            //==============================================================================
        }else{ //DO FEATURED ==================================================================
            //==============================================================================

            $limit_per_page = $limit_per_page - $featured_posts->found_posts;

            //EXCLUDE FEATURED POST TO AVOID REPETITION on FIRST PAGE
            $featured_ids = array();
            if($have_featured===true){

                while ( $featured_posts->have_posts() ) : $featured_posts->the_post();
                    $featured_ids[] = $featured_posts->post->ID;
                endwhile;
            }

            $cs_args = array(
                'posts_per_page'=> $limit_per_page,
                'orderby'       => 'menu_order',
                'order'         => 'ASC',
                'offset'           => 0,
                'post__not_in'     => $featured_ids,
                'post_type'        => 'post',
                'post_status'      => 'publish',
                'suppress_filters' => false,
                'paged' => $paged,
            );

            $posts_merge = new WP_Query( $cs_args );


            //MERGE BOTH QUERIES
            $resources = new WP_Query();
            $resources->posts = array_merge( $featured_posts->posts, $posts_merge->posts );

            //merge counters
            $resources->post_count = $featured_posts->post_count + $posts_merge->post_count;
            $resources->found_posts = $featured_posts->found_posts + $posts_merge->found_posts;
        }


    //==============================================================================
    else: //LOAD ALL POST OR SHOW 2 PAGE POSTS
    //==============================================================================



        //EXCLUDE FEATURED POST TO AVOID REPETITION ON OTHER PAGES
        $featured_ids = array();
        if($have_featured===true){

            while ( $featured_posts->have_posts() ) : $featured_posts->the_post();
                $featured_ids[] = $featured_posts->post->ID;
            endwhile;
        }



        $cs_args = array(
            'posts_per_page'   => $limit_per_page,
            'orderby' => 'menu_order',
            'order'        => 'ASC',
            'offset'           => 0,
            'meta_key'         => $meta_key,
            'meta_value'       => $meta_value,
            'meta_compare'     => 'LIKE',
            'post_type'        => 'resource',
            'post__not_in'     => $featured_ids,
            'post_status'      => 'publish',
            'paged' => $paged,
        );

        $resources = new WP_Query( $cs_args );

    endif;


    //==============================================================================
    //FILL DROPDOWNS ==========================================
    //==============================================================================


    //POPULATE SECTORS
    $sectors_args = array(
        'posts_per_page'   => 100,
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'offset'           => 0,
        'cat'              => '',
        'include'          => '',
        'exclude'          => '',
        'meta_key'         => '',
        'meta_value'       => '',
        'post_type'        => 'page',
        'post_mime_type'   => '',
        'post_parent'      => 101,
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
        'suppress_filters' => false
    );

    $sectors = new WP_Query( $sectors_args );

    //POPULATE SERVICES
    $services_args = array(
        'posts_per_page'   => 100,
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'offset'           => 0,
        'cat'              => '',
        'include'          => '',
        'exclude'          => '',
        'meta_key'         => '',
        'meta_value'       => '',
        'post_type'        => 'page',
        'post_mime_type'   => '',
        'post_parent'      => 18,
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
        'suppress_filters' => false
    );

    $services = new WP_Query( $services_args );

    //POPULATE JURISDICTION
    $jurisdiction = get_field_object('field_54fd9b5caf94e');

    //==============================================================================
    //=== RESET POST ARRAY ======================================================
    //==============================================================================
    wp_reset_postdata();


?>

<div class="introBanner">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="introInner col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="titleArea">
                <div class="title">
                                    <?
                                    $banner_title = get_field('banner_title');
                                    $title_shown = get_field('title_shown');
                                    if (!empty($banner_title)) {
                                    ?>
                                    <h1><?php echo $banner_title;?></h1>
                                    <? } else { ?>
                                    <h1><?php echo $title_shown;?></h1>
                                    <? } ?>
                    <div class="darkBlueOverlay">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="copy">
                <p><?php echo get_field('banner_text');?></p>
            </div>

            <div class="darkBlueOverlayFull">&nbsp;</div>

            <img src="<?php echo get_field('banner_image');?>" alt="<?php echo get_field('title_shown');?>">
        </div>

        <?php if($is_translation===false):?>
            <div class="searchPanel">
                <div class="searchFilter resources-page">

                    <form action="<?php echo get_permalink( $page_id ); ?>" method="post" name="search_filter">

                        <div class="formGroup" rel="1">
                            <select class="selectpicker" >

                                <option value="null"><?php _e('Services','bonestheme');?></option>

                                <?php   while ( $services->have_posts() ) : $services->the_post(); ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $services->post->ID;?>" <?php if($service_match == $services->post->ID){echo 'selected="selected"';}?>><?php the_title();?></option>
                                <?php
                                    echo sub_services_resources($services->post->ID,$service_match);
                                endwhile;   ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="formGroup" rel="2">
                            <select class="selectpicker" >

                                <option value="null"><?php _e('Sectors','bonestheme');?></option>

                                <?php   while ( $sectors->have_posts() ) : $sectors->the_post();?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $sectors->post->ID;?>" <?php if($sector_match == $sectors->post->ID){echo 'selected="selected"';}?>><?php the_title();?></option>
                                <?php endwhile; ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="formGroup" rel="3">
                            <select class="selectpicker">

                                <option value="null"><?php _e('Jurisdiction','bonestheme');?></option>

                                <?php foreach($jurisdiction['choices'] as $xx){ ?>
                                    <option <?php if(strcmp(str_replace($remove,"",$juris_match),str_replace($remove,"",$xx))==0){echo 'selected="selected"';}?>><?php echo $xx;?></option>';
                                <?php };?>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="formGroup last" rel="4">
                            <input type="text" name="option" value="<?php echo $searchx;?>" placeholder="<?php _e('Search by keyword','bonestheme');?>" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="group" value="4" />
                            <input type="submit" class="search-submit">
                        </div>

                        <div class="resetme"><a href="#">Reset all</a></div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endif;?>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="contentArea">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="copyContainerFull col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div id="masonryTrigger" class="resourcesContainer col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="gridSizer"></div>

                    <?php while ( $resources->have_posts() ) : $resources->the_post();
                        $image_on = (get_field('cs_image'))? true:false;
                        if($image_on):  ?>

                            <a class="box boxWide" href="<?php echo get_the_permalink();?>">
                                <img src="<?php echo get_field('cs_image');?>" alt="" class="pull-left" />
                                <div class="boxContent col-md-8 col-sm-12">
                                    <h3><?php echo get_field('cs_title');?> </h3>
                                    <p><?php echo get_field('cs_teaser');?></p>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        <?php else:?>

                            <a class="box" href="<?php echo get_the_permalink();?>">
                                <div class="boxContent">
                                    <h3><?php echo get_field('cs_title');?> </h3>
                                    <p><?php echo get_field('cs_teaser');?></p>
                                </div>
                            </a>

                        <?php endif;?>

                    <?php endwhile;?>

                    <?php if($resources->found_posts==0){ _e( $empty, 'bonestheme' );}?>
                </div>

                <?php
                $accumulated_limit = ($limit_per_page + $featured_count ) * $paged;

                if(($resources->found_posts > $accumulated_limit)&&($filter_option_array===false)): ?>

                    <div class="loadMore col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <a class="ctaBtn" href="#" rel="<?php echo "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']  . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] .'?page=2'; ?>">Load more...</a>
                    </div>

                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```